# How to stop a service with lokkit?

Tags: centos, firewall

On centos

> sudo lokkit -s http
>   opens up the service.
>   I have been reading the documentation and I was googling for a while, but I cannot figure out how to turn off the service (undo the result of the above). Surely the writers of lokkit must have thought that that would be needed, so it must be there somewhere. Thanks!